# Django dynamic URL with data from DB

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework, url-rewriting

****Models.py****

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class reviewData(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    review_content = models.TextField()
    star_num = models.FloatField()
class buildingData(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building_loc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building_call = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

****views.py****

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import reviewData
from .models import buildingData
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import ReviewSerializer

class BuildingInfoAPI(APIView):
    def get(request):
        queryset = buildingData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    def get(request):
        queryset = reviewData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

****urls.py****

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from crawling_data.views import ReviewListAPI
from crawling_data.views import BuildingInfoAPI

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/buildingdata/', BuildingInfoAPI.as_view()),
    #path('api/buildingdata/(I want to put building name here)', ReviewListAPI.as_view())

]
```

I am making review api.

I want to use building name as url path to bring reviews for specific buildings

For example, there are a, b, c reviews

a, b reviews are for aaabuilding

c reviews are for xxxbuilding

*api/buildingdata/aaabuilding (only shows aaabuilding review)*

```
{
    building_name = aaabuilding
    review_content = a
    star_num = 5

    building_name = aaabuilding
    review_content = b
    star_num = 3
}
```

*api/buildingdata/xxxbuilding (only shows xxxbuilding review)*

```
{
    building_name = xxxbuilding
    review_content = c
    star_num = 4
}
```

I've searched some dynamic URL posts, but they were not that I want.

Also, I've posted a question before but there was no answer I was looking for.

Is there any way to bring building name into URL from db?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation on [path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters). And usage of django's  [slugify function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify).

In your situation you will want a slug - but there are limitations to using a slug:

- slugs must translate to some unique string, in your case building name. Therefore you should make sure that building name and slug are unique in your model.

You should add a slug field to the model - and also change the review model so it foreign keys to the building model:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class buildingData(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    building_loc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building_call = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.building_name)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        

class reviewData(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(buildingData, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    review_content = models.TextField()
    star_num = models.FloatField()
```

Then in your `urls.py`:

```
path('api/buildingdata/<slug:slug>/', ReviewListAPI.as_view())
```

Then in your `Views.py`:

```
class ReviewListAPI(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        building = get_object_or_404(buildingData, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')
        queryset = building.reviews.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Also review pep8 - your class names should really be BuildingData and ReviewData - and you problably dont need `Data` in the names either.